# MonoTouch Pixate UITableViewCell style setting

Tags: css, xamarin.ios, pixate

Having a tough time getting the styling to apply on a UITableViewCell that has a custom View with a UIImage within it using PIXATE.
I have tried several variations;

```
PixateEngine.SetStyleId(ctrl.MyImage, “myStyle”);

#myStyle {
    border-radius   : 10px;
}
```

also tried,

```
PixateEngine.SetStyleClass(ctrl.MyImage, “myStyle”);

.myStyle {
    border-radius   : 10px;
}
```

Additionally, I have tried setting the styleId and styleClass within the nib file all to no avail.
Is there anything special with UITableViewCell custom and nested object style settings that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has seemed to be addressed in the most recent version of Pixate.